# Create users manually yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I have been given a website made with yii 1.1.1.4 and i want to create new users. The issue that i can only create these users manually because there is no registration form. I have tried creating these users using the following line of code to get a hashed password and then add this password to the database along with the other user credentials (username and email). The problem is that when I try to log in with the correct credentials I get an error. What is the correct way of adding a new user manually?
The code i used in order to get the hashed password is:

```
$newPassword = '123456as';
$hashedPassword = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($newPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will need this but the solution that worked for me was to hash a password of my choice and echo it in a teplate. Then I copied the hashed password and added it to the password field in my database
The code I used:

```
   $password = '1234567';
   $newpass = hash('sha512', $password);
   echo $newpass
```